# Problema ao montar servidor angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Boa tarde galera, estou tendo problema ao tentar ao rodar um projeto angular js, pois só trabalhei com angular 2+, na hora que executo um npm start o seguinte erro ocorre:

> npm ERR! missing script: start
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-19T15_33_46_553Z-debug.log

Log informado:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Users\\pedro.mindtek\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (D:\Users\pedro.mindtek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:90:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
5 verbose cwd D:\IBGE\workspaces\Agatha\adaptacao-RedHat-OpenShift\agatha\codigo-fonte\cliente
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Users\\pedro.mindtek\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v8.11.3
9 verbose npm  v6.7.0
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Alguém poderia me informar como faço pra montar o servidor do Angular Js? Eu já peguei o projeto pronto aqui na empresa e está complicado faze-lo funcionar.

Comment: Tá dizendo que não existe nenhum script chamado start.

Answer (score 0):

Não é um erro de Angular, é um erro de NodeJS.

Você precisa definir o que rodar com o comando `npm start`. Normalmente, nós executamos o script com o comando `node [caminho do script]`, mas para facilitar nossas vidas, podemos definir atalhos no package.json para não termos que digitar o caminho do script principal toda vez.

Então no package.json, defina a propriedade:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js", //exemplo
}
```